# How to install linux from hard disk(not in vmware or alike)?

Tags: linux, installation

I've already downloaded the fedora image [here](http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/13/Live/i686/Fedora-13-i686-Live.iso),

and the OS is windows XP,

how to I install it without inserting a CD ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install Fedora from the live media .iso. Only the normal install media .iso can be used for this.

Comment: What's the difference between **live** and **normal** media .iso ?

Comment: The live media is about the size of a CD. Burning it onto a CD and booting from it will result in a usable Fedora desktop, running from the CD. It contains a compressed ext3 or ext4 filesystem with the packages already extracted. The normal media is about the size of a single-layer DVD. Booting from it will start the graphical installer. It is a normal ISO9660 disc, with the packages available for installation.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to burn a CD, install to a VM, set up a PXE server (to install across the network to another machine), or use something like [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a bootable USB stick, which you can then install from.

You can't just magically install an iso file onto the machine it's stored on.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu Linux the WUBI is avaiable.
http://wubi-installer.org/

With this installer you can install ubuntu on to your pc while running Windows.
I don't know if Fedora has a similar installer.

There is some more advanced and complicated way to achieve what you want with nearly every linux installer:
http://marc.herbert.free.fr/linux/win2linstall.html